# How to get jQuery click events to fire from a dynamically Generated Ajax script

Tags: jquery, ajax, binding

So i have researched and played with many examples but now it has been a waste of a pretty sunny day so I am asking for help.

I have a basic php page that displays Motorcycle chain information with a button that i use to call another php script to populate a modal JQuery box.  This page populates as expected from the call to the script and displays the data and all looks well.

So now my previously built event handler for the links isnt firing as expected, my question is when do i bind my links, i would think after the data is populated from the ajax script.

I tried it everywhere i am at a loss below are the code snippets hopefully someone can see my error or errors.

I know someone else is in this same boat or at least have had experience with this common problem.

Thanks again!

```
$(function() {  

    // Attempt at Getting binding to work after 
    // Dynamically generated code from ajax call
     $( ".chainSelected" ).on('click', 'a', function(event) {
         alert('clicked');
         event.preventDefault();
         return false;
     });

      $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          height: 400,
          width: 750,
          modal: true,
            Cancel: function() {
                      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
              }             
        });

        $( "#selectChain" )
          .click(function(event) {
            if($('#pitch').val() == '*' ) {
               event.preventDefault();
               alert ('You have to pick a chain pitch first.');
               $('#pitch').focus();
            } else {

                $.ajax({
                      type: 'GET',
                      url: 'includes/select-chain.php',
                      data: { pitch: +  $('#pitch').val() },
                      beforeSend:function(){
                        // load a temporary image in a div
                      },
                      success:function(data){
                        $('#dialog-form').html(data);
                      },
                      error:function(){
                        $('#dialog-form').html('<p class="error"><strong>Oops!</strong></p>');
                      }
                    });

                 $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );  

          }

          });

        /* Once a chain is selected update the contents to the form field for storing */
        $( ".chainSelected" )
          .click(function() {
            $partNumber = $( this ).attr('href');
            $partNumber = $partNumber.substring(1);
            $partDesc = $(this).text();
            $( "#chainSelectedPartNumber").val( $partNumber );
            $( "#chainSelectedDesc" ).text( $partNumber + '-' + $partDesc );
            $( "#linkedChainPartDescription").val( $( "#chainSelectedDesc" ).text() );
            // Reformat the part number per Brian's Request
            $masterPartNumber = $('#masterPartNumber').val();
            if( $masterPartNumber.indexOf('-') != -1) {   // xxxxxxxx-9
                hyph = $masterPartNumber.indexOf('-');
                $masterPartNumber = $masterPartNumber.substr(0, hyph) + '-' + $(this).attr('alt');
            } else {
                $masterPartNumber = $masterPartNumber + "-" + $(this).attr('alt');
            }               
            $('#masterPartNumber').val( $masterPartNumber );  // main part number
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "close" );

          });
});        



</script
```

> Here is what the popup HTML markup looks like

```
<a href="#DA520ERT2" alt="1" class="chainSelected">D.I.D. 520ERT2 GOLD PLATED LIGHTWEIGHT NON-O'RING OFF-ROAD CHAIN (450cc Rated) </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to defer binding the event handler; use event delegation to listen from a parent element

```
 // or some other more immediate parent element
 $( "body" ).on('click', 'a.chainSelected', function(event) {
     alert('clicked');
     event.preventDefault();
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response I added your code and still nothing fires. i would hate to have to embed onClick events in my script.